# How get a part of a $_SESSION array?

Tags: php, arrays, session

How do I get a part of a $_session array?

```
<?php
session_start();

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {
    echo $product_id . "=>" . $quantity . "<br>";

}
?>
```

This outputs

```
1 => 6
4 => 5
2 => 5
```

But what I ultimately want is the value of only one of them.
Lets say I only want the second( 4 => 5 ).

So I tried this :echo $_SESSION['cart'][1];
And ofcourse it showed me nothing.

So my question is how to get it. Sorry if this is a stupid/unclear question.

Comment: `$_SESSION['cart'][1]` *should* give you `6` in this case...!?

Comment: Please give a use case for what you're using this for. With an array you typically either want to access a specific key or go through all keys. What is the point in getting just the "second" entry?

Comment: Your keys are probably being stored as strings in an associative array, not integers. $_SESSION['cart']['4'] should give you 5.

Comment: @jtv4k Numeric string keys are (almost) always stored as integers: http://codepad.org/rcDO5FHh

Comment: @Jim very true! I should have focused on the "associative array" part. I should have made the point that PHP doesn't "index" its arrays, so expecting item 2 in the array isn't the same as $x[1].

Comment: The reason why $_SESSION['cart'][1] wouldn't give me any values was because there was a space before and after for some reason. So $_SESSION['cart'][ 1 ] would give me the right value of 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not able to replicate your issue.

Check this **test.php**:

```
<?php

// Start PHP Session
session_start();

// Dummy Data
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(
    1 => 6,
    4 => 5,
    2 => 5
);

// Helper Function
function getSessionCartData($key) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$key])) {
        return $_SESSION['cart'][$key];
    }
    return false;
}

// Usage
var_dump(getSessionCartData(4));
```

Output:

```
int 5
```

Comment: This works very well! Thanks you for the effort and everybpdy else.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]`

If the `$product_id` is 1, your output from the code above will give you 6.